# Failing to statically link to OpenCV 4.7.0 using CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cmake, linker-errors

I have compiled OpenCV from scratch using `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`. I've looked at the output and it seems to be correctly generating static libraries (`.lib` as I am on Windows).

However, when I try to link to the generated files using CMake's `find_package` mechanism, it seems to tell the linker to look for dynamic libraries and I get `LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease'` errors.

Here are the minimum examples to reproduce the problem.

1. Download OpenCV 4.7.0 and build on Windows with:

```
cmake -S .\sources\ -B opencv-build-test -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
cmake --build .\opencv-build-test\
```

2A. Create the following project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)

project(OpenCVStaticLinkingTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(OpenCV 4.7.0 REQUIRED EXACT)

add_executable(OpenCVStaticLinkingTest main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(OpenCVStaticLinkingTest  ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

2B. With this main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    // Create an OpenCV matrix
    cv::Mat testMatrix(5, 5, CV_32F);

    // Interact with it to show we've gone this far
    std::cout << "Value 1,1: " + std::to_string(testMatrix.at<float>(1,1)) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

3. Then build as follows:

```
cmake -S . -B example-build -D OpenCV_DIR=$WHEREVER_YOU_BUILT_IT
cmake --build example-build
```

I am using VS 17 to compile on Windows 11, and have tried both with and without Ninja.

Everything online seems to tell me that compiling with `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` should be all I need to do, but clearly something is wrong. I've tried:

- Compiling also with and without the `OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=YES` flag
- Setting `OpenCV_STATIC` to on my project
- Setting `OpenCV_SHARED` to on my project
- Both of the above together
- Setting `set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")`
- Setting

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
```

But so far getting always the same problem.

Comment: `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` does not mean to use static runtime. It means create static libraries instead of dynamic / shared ones.

Comment: Related: [https://discourse.cmake.org/t/msvc-runtime-library-defaults-to-dynamic-linking-for-static-libraries/4084](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/msvc-runtime-library-defaults-to-dynamic-linking-for-static-libraries/4084)

Comment: There is a custom CMake option in CMakeLists of OpenCV: `BUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT`, default to ON if MSVC: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.8.1/CMakeLists.txt#L493. If you want to build static OpenCV libs linked to shared CRT: `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT=OFF`.

Comment: Another solution is to build you own executable against static CRT and link to static OpenCV linked to static CRT. You'll have to pass `-DCMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY=MultiThreaded` while calling cmake configuration against your own project, because otherwise it builds against shared CRT. IMHO, OpenCV CMakeLists is bad regarding default CRT when BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is OFF, it doesn't honor principle of least surprise.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes the `BUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT` default to ON is interesting to me.  I think that is what the OP wants but curious why it did not work. I keep forgetting the order of what msvc displays this error message (because I rarely get it myself / always use dynamic runtime with shared libs). Does the error say OpenCV has a dynamic runtime or the application that the OP is building?

Comment: I don't remember either. But since `BUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT` is `ON` by default in OpenCV (defeating default CMake behavior), I guess that in `LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease'`, the second mentioned CRT refers to app being linked, and the first CRT to the lib that app links to. In other word, error says that linker has found a CRT (first one) in libs linked into app incompatible with CRT specified for app .

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you, you summarized my misunderstanding of the error message, I hadn't understood yet the linking to the CRT was the problem. SpacePotatoes, that's the correct summary of the solution to the problem (explicitly compile one to the same CRT as the other). If you care about such things, you can put that as an answer and I'll flag it as the correct answer.

Comment: @SpacePotatoes pinging space potatoes for the above. Odd you can only ping one user...

Comment: PS: I can confirm trying to force dynamic CRT linking of OpenCV doesn't seem to work so the solution is really to do 
`set(CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")` on my project.